# Select with group by and count two columns

Tags: postgresql

I have this table

```
+----+----------------------------+---------------+----------+
| ID |         CREATED_AT         |   CATEGORY    |   TYPE   |
+----+----------------------------+---------------+----------+
|  1 | 2017-11-23 23:00:40.221958 | SEM COBERTURA | callback |
|  2 | 2017-11-23 22:58:36.970052 | VENDA         | ativo    |
|  3 | 2017-11-23 22:47:03.956185 | SEM COBERTURA | ativo    |
|  4 | 2017-11-23 22:42:24.309915 | VENDA         | ativo    |
|  5 | 2017-11-23 22:32:48.780418 | SEM COBERTURA | callback |
|  6 | 2017-11-23 22:12:21.631433 | VENDA         | callback |
|  7 | 2017-11-23 22:09:38.52699  | SEM COBERTURA | ativo    |
|  8 | 2017-11-23 22:08:09.836343 | LIGACAO MUDA  | callback |
|  9 | 2017-11-23 22:08:07.058063 | SEM COBERTURA | callback |
| 10 | 2017-11-23 22:07:02.067439 | LIGACAO MUDA  | other    |
+----+----------------------------+---------------+----------+
```

With the table above, i want group by and sum the column TYPE and sum the CATEGORY "VENDA", eg:

This is what i want

```
+----------+------------+----------------+
|   TYPE   | COUNT_TYPE | COUNT_CATEGORY_VENDA |
+----------+------------+----------------+
| callback |          5 |              1 |
| ativo    |          4 |              2 |
| other    |          1 |              0 |
+----------+------------+----------------+
```

The type "callback" appear 5 times and has 1 category "VENDA", "ativo" appear 4 times and has 2 "VENDA"...

To get TYPE and COUNT_TYPE i'm using this query:

```
SELECT TYPE, count(TYPE) AS COUNT_TYPE FROM table WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2017-11-23 00:00:00' AND '2017-11-23 23:59:00' GROUP BY TYPE ORDER BY COUNT_TYPE DESC
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use case when in postgresql

```
SELECT TYPE, count(TYPE) AS COUNT_TYPE, SUM(case CATEGORY when 'VENDA' then 1 else 0 end) FROM table WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2017-11-23 00:00:00' AND '2017-11-23 23:59:00' GROUP BY TYPE ORDER BY COUNT_TYPE DESC
```

Comment: Thanks @CanFil. Is exactly what i want.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. IMHO the most simple way is to use `case when` to filter what to count in query.

```
SELECT
  TYPE,
  count(TYPE) AS COUNT_TYPE,
  SUM(
    case CATEGORY when 'VENDA' then 1 else 0 end
  ) AS COUNT_CATEGORY_VENDA
FROM table
WHERE
  created_at BETWEEN '2017-11-23 00:00:00' AND '2017-11-23 23:59:00' 
GROUP BY TYPE
ORDER BY COUNT_TYPE DESC;
```

Besides `CASE col WHEN d1 THEN v1 WHEN d2 THEN v2 ELSE v3 END`, you can also try `CASE WHEN col = d1 THEN v1 WHEN col = d2 THEN v2 ELSE v3 END`.

Another way is to use sub-queries.

Comment: count will not solve the situation, he should use sum

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. but as @CanFil said. I had to use SUM instead CASE